# Displaying Array Values in Select Dropdown using ng-options

Tags: angularjs

```
  {

    "numDetails" : [

                         {

                           "code" : "ABC",

                           "num" : "246810","4681012","681012"},

                         {   
                           "code" : "DEF",

                           "num" : "13579","357913","5791315"}

                       ]

   }
```

when code is ABC selected the num values should be displayed one by one in options.Please let me know how to write ng-options in html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I got you correctly then you are looking for something like this

```
<doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="HomeCtrl">

<select ng-model="opt" ng-options="obj.num as obj.code for obj in opts">
      <option value="">select</option>
</select>

<select ng-model="opt1" ng-options= "obj1 for obj1 in opt">
     <option value="">select</option>
</select>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>

angular.module('myApp', []);

angular.module('myApp').controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

 $scope.opts =  [

                         {

                           "code" : "ABC",

                           "num" : ["246810","4681012","681012"]
                         },

                         {   
                           "code" : "DEF",

                           "num" : ["13579","357913","5791315"]
                         }

                ]         

}]);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```